# PHP Pagination: Won't Display in next page

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

Good Day! I have a problem in my pagination, my pagination will display the data that is between from date (January 1, 2018) to date (January 31, 2018), at first page it's working properly. When I click the next page the result are gone and I have to re entry the data Between the Date. Here's my Pagination Code.

```
<th><input type="text" name="from" id="from" class="tcal"> to <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="tcal"><br><br></th>
<th><input type="submit" class="button" value=""></th>
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'efms');

$results_per_page = 20;
$from=@$_POST['from'];
$to=@$_POST['to'];
$sql="SELECT *, SUM(rqty), SUM(iqty), SUM(bbal), COUNT(item), COUNT(description) FROM issuances WHERE trandate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY item, description, category ORDER BY item, description, category ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$number_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);

$number_of_pages = ceil($number_of_results/$results_per_page);

if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
$page = 1;
} else {
$page = $_GET['page'];
}

$this_page_first_result = ($page-1)*$results_per_page;

$from=@$_POST['from'];
$to=@$_POST['to'];
$sql="SELECT *, SUM(rqty), SUM(iqty), SUM(bbal), COUNT(item), COUNT(description) FROM issuances WHERE trandate BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to' GROUP BY item, description, category ORDER BY item, description, category ASC LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' .  $results_per_page;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id=$row['id'];
$item=$row['item'];
$description=$row['description'];
$rqty=$row['SUM(rqty)'];
$iqty=$row['SUM(iqty)'];
$bqty=$row['bqty']; 
$bbal=$row['SUM(bbal)'];    
$totqtyb=$bbal+$rqty-$iqty;
echo "<th width='80px' class='text-left left bottom right'>$item ($description)</th>";
echo "<th width='80px' class='right bottom'>$bbal</th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'></th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'></th>";
echo "<th width='80px' class='right bottom'>$rqty</th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'></th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'></th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'>$rqty</th>";
echo "<th width='80px' class='right bottom'>$iqty</th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'></th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'></th>";
echo "<th width='100px' class='right bottom'>$totqtyb</th>";
echo "</tr>";
}
for ($page=1;$page<=$number_of_pages;$page++) {
echo '<b><a href="efms.php?page=' . $page . '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . $page . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></b>';
}
?>
```

The Result of my Pagination and my Desired Output.

[First Page Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDeGQ.jpg)

[Next Page Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p39dN.jpg)

[My Desired Output When Click Next Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x22bX.jpg)

Comment: No `$_POST` data are sent when you "click on a link", only when you submit a form.

Comment: What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

No `$_POST` data are sent when you "click on a link", only when you submit a form.

So, you could do something like this :

- Change the `method` of the `<form>` to `"GET"`,
- Change to way you get the `from` and `to` (and see bottom note 2) :

  ```
  $from = isset($_GET['from']) ? $_GET['from'] : '' ; // or change '' to a default initial date. 
  $to = isset($_GET['to']) ? $_GET['to'] : '' ; // or change '' to a default end date.
  ```
- Change your pagination links :

  ```
  echo '<a href="efms.php?page=' . $page . '&from=' . $from . '&to=' . $to .'">...</a>' ;
  ```
- Write your `<input>` tags after getting `$from` and `$to` to fill them with those values.

  ```
  echo '<th><input type="text" name="from" id="from" class="tcal" value="'.$from.'"> 
        to 
        <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="tcal" value="'.$to.'"><br><br></th>' ;
  ```

Another method could be to store `$from` and `$to` into the `$_SESSION` and change them if something is posted.

Finally, and **important notes** :

1. you should have a look to [`mysqli_prepare()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to secure you queries against [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).
2. you should secure your input data to prevent your site from [XSS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php).

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried but it's not properly working or I'm not that good. The pagination link won't display.

I'm not familiar with mysqli_prepare() / SQL Injections / XSS attack, but i will take your note.